# Drive API: Domain-wide delegation so admin can grant permissions on behalf of users?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Schools will install my application as a Google Apps app.  Right now I request the drive scope, so my app can read/write all of the current user's drive files.  How can I ask a domain administrator to grant that privilege to my app on behalf of all of the users in the domain, so that each individual person doesn't have to understand & grant the permissions later?

Answer (score 0):

If you build and publish your app to the Google Apps Marketplace, domain administrators can install your and pre-approve access for all users of the domain. You can find details at https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm afraid I can't find details there - the section on "publishing your app" tells me how to publish on the Chrome Web Store (not the Google Apps Marketplace), and when I do that the domain administrator is not given a chance to grant the permissions for each user.  Do you have a more specific link?

Comment: Actually, the Google Apps Marketplace uses the Chrome Webstore behind the scenes. You use the same Chrome Webstore developer account to publish. What makes it a Google Apps Marketplace app is specifying `"container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"]`. That will list it in the CPanel instead of chrome.google.com/webstore.

Comment: I was starting to get that impression, thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately, listing DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE and USES_DRIVE (or whatever it is) does NOT prompt the installer to grant access on behalf of all users, at least in the "test install-process" flow I can start from the API Console.

Comment: Ah, I think that's because the test flow only tests install flow of a web app, not the Drive app. That's a good feature request. Can you try listing just to your domain or a test users?